# insert single linked list at the end recursively in c

Tags: c, tree, insert, binary-tree

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?
I want to create non- return function `void` to insert a node at the end of linked list.

```
void insert_tail_Recursively(struct node **phead, int key) {
  if (*phead == NULL) {
    Node*temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = key;
    temp->pLeft = temp->pRight = NULL;
    *phead = temp;
  } else {
    Node*temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->data = key;
    temp->pLeft = temp->pRight = NULL;

    /* data more than root node data insert at right */
    if ((temp->data > (*phead)->data) && ((*phead)->pRight != NULL)) 
      insert_tail_Recursively((*phead)->pRight, key);
    else if ((temp->data > (*phead)->data) && ((*phead)->pRight == NULL)) {
      (*phead)->pRight = temp;

    }

    /* data less than root node data insert at left */
    else if ((temp->data < (*phead)->data) && ((*phead)->pLeft != NULL)) 
      insert_tail_Recursively((*phead)->pLeft, key);
    else if ((temp->data < (*phead)->data) && ((*phead)->pLeft == NULL)) {
      (*phead)->pLeft = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does this condition  temp->data < (*phead)->data mean? How is it related to the "end of the list"?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You are asking about adding to the list, but code is about adding to the tree. There is no definition of `struct node`. Even after adding it, the code does not compile properly. Please fix compilation errors, they are meaningful here.

Comment: You should not do this recursively.  You will surely bust the stack if your list is huge.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated and as result has bugs. For example there are memory leaks.

It seems you mean the following.

```
void insert_tail_Recursively( struct node **phead, int key )
{
    if ( *phead == NULL )
    {
        *phead = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
        ( *phead )->data = key;
        ( *phead )->pLeft = ( *phead )->pRight = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        phead = key < ( *phead )->data ? &( *phead )->pLeft : &( *phead )->pRight;
        insert_tail_Recursively( phead, key );
    }
}
```

Comment: Very clean and terse tree insertion code, plus 1 from me

Comment: Isn't this a problem? Your function will modify the original root pointer passed to it.

Comment: @Coldspeed Yes, it will modify the root in the case when the tree is empty and the pointer is equal to NULL. But it is not a problem. It is a solution.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow and when it's not NULL, you still see it is updated inside the recursive case. So in a non-empty tree this will always make the root point to the leaf, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Coldspeed In the case  when the tree is not empty it is ( *phead )->pLeft and ( *phead )->pRight that are updated. because phead is set with the addresses of these nodes.